# Can you build a settlement anywhere if you have the resources for a settlement and a road?

Tags: catan

In Settlers of Catan, it says you need a road to build a new settlement (placement rules apply). If you have the resources available to build both at the same time, can this settlement be played wherever the player wants it to go?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No

Your first two settlements (placed during set-up) are special and can be placed in any valid position on the board, after that new settlements **must** be connected by road to existing settlements.

The relevant parts of the [rules](http://www.catan.com/service/game-rules) are:

- Under building roads (bottom of page 4) it says "A new road must always connect to 1 of your existing roads, settlements, or cities."
- Under building settlements (top of page 5) it says "Each of your settlements must
  connect to at least 1 of your own roads."

Note that you can build as much as you like per turn, so you could build several road segments and a settlement in the same turn (as long as you have the resources).